# ajax changes target attribute on multipart/form-data form

Tags: ajax, jsf, mojarra

When I try to render a component with f:ajax inside a **multipart/form-data** form, the **target** attribute of the form gets changed to **JSFFrameId**. Is this a bug?

Here is a sample code when this occur:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputText>
        <f:ajax event="change" render="@this" execute="@this"/>
    </h:inputText>
    <h:inputFile />
</h:form>
```

In my real code this is not what I'm trying to do but the same issue occurs with the sample code.

When visiting this page I get the following HTML output:

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="/AdApp/faces/test.xhtml" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="form">
    <input id="form-textfield" type="text" name="form-textfield" onchange="mojarra.ab(this,event,'change','@this','@this')">
    <input id="form-filefield" type="file" name="form-filefield">
    <input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1-javax.faces.ViewState-0" value="-1920816151200438245:-3719618601043085373" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

Nothing wrong here. But when the ajax event triggers, this is what happends with the HTML output(My issue? target attribute of the form):

```
<form id="form" name="form" target="JSFFrameId" method="POST" action="http://DOMAIN_PATH/AdApp/faces/test.xhtml" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="form">
    <input id="form-textfield" type="text" name="form-textfield" onchange="mojarra.ab(this,event,'change','@this','@this')">
    <input id="form-filefield" type="file" name="form-filefield">
    <input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1-javax.faces.ViewState-0" value="-1920816151200438245:-3719618601043085373" autocomplete="off">
</form>
<iframe src="about:blank" id="JSFFrameId" name="JSFFrameId" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0">
    <partial-response id="j_id1">
        <changes>
            <update id="form-textfield">
                <![CDATA[<input id="form-textfield" type="text" name="form-textfield" value="das" onchange="mojarra.ab(this,event,'change','@this','@this')" />]]>
            </update>
            <update id="j_id1-javax.faces.ViewState-0">
                <![CDATA[-1920816151200438245:-3719618601043085373]]>
            </update>
        </changes>
    </partial-response>
</iframe>
```

I don't care about the iframe keeping a record of the changes. My issue is that the target of the form has been changed. So after the ajax event triggers, a submit will target a hidden iframe and not the window itself.

If I remove the **enctype** attribute or set ajax to render **@form** instead, it doesn't change the **target** attribute. I need the **enctype="multipart/form-data"** to upload files, and I dont want to use **render="@form"** because some of the content in my real form might have been modified by javascript code. Am I missing something? Or just bug? I will add some javascript to remove the target attribute but if I'm doing something wrong, I should use another approach.

I'm using the following tools:

Netbeans IDE 8

Glassfish 4 with Mojarra 2.2.7

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be a couple ([2843](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2843), [3018](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3018), [3048](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3048)) of bugs related to fileuploads and ajax-reloads. They all are marked as resolved in various versions (JSF 2.2.1 and 2.2.5). I am on 2.2.3 and I am not in charge of the JSF versioning so i'm stuck with that. I tried 2.2.8 on my development machine, but could still reproduce the problem.

Like you, i also found out that using `render="@form"` leads to a problem with disappearing changes. However, if I also add `execute="@form"` the changes are stored in the bean and are remain visible after the render.