# JSF inputFile Refused to display 'mypage.xhtml' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I was following [this answer by BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677397/how-to-upload-file-using-jsf-2-2-hinputfile-where-is-the-saved-file) to try and upload a file to the server. I am using his code as-is.

When using JSF 2.2, the `#{bean.save}` was never reached, and the file was never saved.

The server's console showed nothing. But the js console showed this error:

```
Refused to display 'http://localhost:8080/my_app/hello.xhtml' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces:1 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at FrameTransport.callback (http://localhost:8080/my_app/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces:1:5109)
    at HTMLIFrameElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/my_app/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces:1:5759)
```

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772011/ajax-changes-target-attribute-on-multipart-form-data-form) which suggested it was a bug in JSF 2.2. So I uploaded to 2.3.

With JSF 2.3 the `#{bean.save}` is reached, and the file is successfully saved. But the js error remains, and I can't upload a second file.

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT** in case it helps: I don't know why, but after selecting the file to upload in the dialog, an `<iframe>` is added to my page somehow.

---

**EDIT 2**

BalusC and Selaron suggested I try to change the X-Frame-Options header to not 'DENY'. I tried adding a `@WebFilter` and setting the header there, like this:

```
public void doFilter(...) 
{ 
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res; 
    response.addHeader("X-Frame-Options", "sameorigin"); 
    response.setHeader("MyHeader", "whatever"); 
    chain.doFilter(req, res); 
}
```

I added a second header MyHeader with value "whatever" to check if the response contained that header when getting to the browser.

Turns out MyHeader gets to the browser correctly, but X-Frame-Options still remains as 'DENY'.

---

As I'm using Spring Security, I figured maybe there was some other filter messing with my response?

So, I have this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BasicConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ...
        http.addFilterAfter(
            new CustomFilter(), SwitchUserFilter.class);    
        ...
    }
}
```

My `CustomFilter` works as the previous one I showed: MyHeader remains, but X-Frame-Options does not.

I added it after `SwitchUserFilter` because the doc for `HttpSecurity.addFilter` says that is the last filter in the chain.

I am a bit lost now. My couple of questions:

1. Am I right to assume the X-Frame-Options header is getting overwritten by some other filter?
2. How could I ensure the X-Frame-Options I set remains? Or, how can I put my filter at the end of the chain?

Comment: The error suggests that your app or server returns `X-Frame-Options:deny` response header. Is this true? Turn off it and retry. Ajax based file uploads can in older browsers only take place via an iframe.

Comment: Hi @BalusC. I am having some trouble with setting the header. I am updating my question

Comment: Effectively, on the technical level, you have a new question. 1: Not per say, can also be a reverse proxy, loadbalancer or such. 2: by using the mechanisms available for this described in other existing Q/A in Stackoverflow

Comment: 2: first part: by checking if other systems override this (can even be a browser plugin)

Comment: And if the filters do not work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe for 'proxy' things

Comment: As you use Spring Security you might adjust the header this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647136/how-to-disable-x-frame-options-response-header-in-spring-security

Answer (score 3):

I found this issue where the Mojarra team planned to [Implement "ajax" file upload #2577](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/2577) and the [commit actually implementing it to the jsf javascript](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/commit/4a95c139c5f920b0363ccb489fba80d7779c9af4).
Madly the documentation on issue 2577 are not accessible anymore and thus it does not explain the background on why an iframe is needed here.

The first passage of [this blog](https://www.viralpatel.net/ajax-style-file-uploading-using-hidden-iframe/) gives a brief explanation on why AJAX file upload is/was(?) not possible directly:

> Ajax Style File Uploading using Hidden iFrame
>   by Viral Patel · November 18, 2008
>
> File uploading using AJAX is not possible. AJAX doesn’t actually post
>   forms to the server, it sends selected data to the server in the form
>   of a POST or GET request. As javascript is not capable of grabbing the
>   file from the users machine and sending it to the server, it’s just
>   not possible with AJAX. You have to resort to regular old form submit.
>   If you have read/seen it somewhere, then it is not through AJAX. File
>   uploading occurs through an iframe in this case. You have to use a
>   iframe to upload the files. So, you can use iframe to asynchronous
>   upload (Like AJAX , but its not AJAX).

So finally your options are to either - as BalusC commented - relax your `X-Frame-Options` header setting or to change your upload to not use AJAX:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputFile value="#{bean.file}" />
    <h:commandButton value="upload" action="#{bean.save}"/>
</h:form>
```

Comment: your solution without ajax works. I will keep trying the ajax way for a little, and if nothing works I will accept the answer